# Matching two pandas dataframes / xarray datasets with slightly different coordinates?

Tags: python, spatial

I have two rather simple dataframes/datasets covering the whole world in 0.5 degrees resolution.

Vegetation categories data

```
biom_df
ind      lat     lon  biome
0      83.25  -43.25      0
1      83.25  -42.75      1
2      83.25  -42.25      1
3      83.25  -39.75      0
4      83.25  -38.75      2
```

and

Population data

```
pop_df
ind         lat      lon  pop2020
0       83.6875 -33.5625        0
1       83.6875 -33.4375        0
2       83.6875 -33.3125        0
3       83.6875 -33.1875        0 
4       83.6875 -33.0625        0
```

The goal is to obtain the **total population sum in each biome category**.

As you can see, the lat and lon coordinates of the two datasets are slightly different, and I haven't figured out how to match them by the "nearest" or "overlapping" grid cells.

I don't care if it is solved with numpy/pandas or xarray.

Thank you for your suggestions!

I tried:

```
biom_ds = biom_df.set_index(['lat','lon']).to_xarray()
pop_ds  = pop_df.set_index(['lat','lon']).to_xarray()
pop_ds.sel(lat = biom_ds.loc[ind].lat, 
           lon = biom_ds.loc[ind].lon, 
           method='nearest')
```

but don't know how to insert that value now into the other dataset.

And I tried:

```
test = pop_df.merge(biom_df, how='outer', on=['lat','lon'])
test = test.sort_values(by=['lat','lon']).reset_index(drop=True)
test['biome'] = test.biome.ffill()
test = test[ (test.lat.isin(pop_df.lat.values)) & (test.lon.isin(pop_df.lat.values)) ]
```

But that seems to be a wrong way to do it, as the result plot shows (see picture)

[image: dataframe_merge_test_result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it interpreted your question right, you want to for each of the rows in `pop_df` find the nearest biome number from `biom_df` and get the sum of population grouped by biome number.

Here's one way to achieve that:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

pop_df["nearest_biome_index"] = cdist(pop_df[["lat", "lon"]].to_numpy(), biom_df[["lat", "lon"]].to_numpy(), metric="euclidean").argmin(axis=1)

print(pop_df.join(biom_df[["biome"]], on="nearest_biome_index").groupby("biome")[["pop2020"]].sum())
```

This would with `cdist` calculate the (euclidean) pairwise distances between each coordinate in `pop_df` and `biom_df`, then find the index of `biom_df` where the distance is the smallest (this code assumes that indices start from 0 and increment by 1).

Then you can join the biome numbers from `biome_df` to `pop_df` based on the indices of the rows that you got with `argmin`, and now you have the number of the nearest biome for each row.

After that it's just a matter of using `group_by` and `sum` to get the sum of population for each biome group.

Comment: Kiitos paljon! This worked like a charm, super elegant and quick! Only now, I have memory issues when trying to do this on the entire data. I guess I have to split the data into parts so that my computer can handle it. I would just try-n-error how many rows at a time it can handle and then loop through the splits. Would you have a more elegant/handy suggestion?

Comment: Do the memory problems occur on the cdist calculation? The pairwise table can for sure get super large if you have a lot of datapoints. Sadly I don't have an elegant solution from the top of my head. Looping is probably the easiest (but not the most elegant) option.